# How to add anchor href property to Option Object?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to to create a hyperlink in a drop-down list in HTML.
I was able to add text to the drop-down but adding href attributes doesn't work with me.
Any advise please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="loadAgeSelector()">
<select id="yearselect"></select>
<script>
function loadAgeSelector()
{
    var startyear = 1900;
    var endyear = 2014;
    for (var i = startyear;i<=endyear;i++){
        node=document.createElement("Option");
        textnode=document.createTextNode(i);
        node.appendChild(textnode);

        var att = document.createAttribute( "href" );
        att.value = "https://www.google.com/" ;
        node.setAttributeNode(att); 
        document.getElementById("yearselect").appendChild(node);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do that with the built-in `select` control. You need to build your own (or use a library).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with 114 `<option href="https://www.google.com/">` (if this was even possible) elements?

Comment: If you want to redirect somewhere when choosing an option, you could attach a `change` event listener on the `<select>` then use `window.location.href`.

Comment: that's usually done with CSS dropdown menu (no JavaScript needed) https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen the change event then handle the link, test the below code:

```
function loadAgeSelector()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("yearselect");
    var startyear = 1900;
    var endyear = 2014;
    for (var i = startyear;i<=endyear;i++){
        node=document.createElement("Option");
        textnode=document.createTextNode(i);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        node.value = "https://www.google.com/?testid=" + i;
        select.appendChild(node);
    }

    select.onchange = function () {
        var link = this.value;
        window.open(link);//or if you want to open in current tab: window.location.href = link;
    }

}
```